# diagonal of the hypercube in cross-attention

Tags: machine-learning, transformer, attention

In Cross-attention, divide the similarity between $Q$ and $K$ by $\sqrt{d_k}$. 
Here $\sqrt{d_k}$ is the diagonal of the hypercube, is this a coincidence or famous theorem?
$$ \frac{QK^T}{\sqrt{d_k}} $$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You first compute the *query embeddings* $Q$ and the *key embeddings* $K$ by multiplying your input sequence $x$ with the query matrix $W_Q$ and the key matrix $W_K$ respectively. Then you calculate the attention scores and scale them by dividing by the dimensionality of the key embedding space.

$$ A = \frac{xW_QW_K^Tx^T}{\sqrt{d_k}} = \frac{QK^T}{\sqrt{d_k}} $$

After that you apply softmax to get the attention weights (probabilities). But to see why we scale by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_k}}$ let’s assume that the query embeddings and key embeddings have zero mean and unit std. Then for the variance of the attention score between any query and key we get:

$$ \alpha = q_i k_j^T = \sum_{n=1}^{d_k} q_{in} k_{jn} $$
$$ \text{Var}(\alpha) = d_k $$
$$ \text{std}(\alpha) = \sqrt{d_k} $$

Applying softmax on the attention scores with such high variance will result in all of the weight being placed on one random element, while all the other elements will have a weight of zero. Thus, in order to have the attention scores with unit std, we scale by $\sqrt{d_k}$.

But is it safe to assume that our query embeddings and key embeddings have unit variance?

The answer is yes. The embeddings are computed by multiplying the input with the query and key matrices ($W_Q$ and $W_K$). We can assume that the input already has unit variance by using a normalizing layer (e.g. LayerNorm), and the weights of the $W_Q$ and $W_K$ matrices should be initialized so that variance is preserved.

For more checkout [this](https://pi-tau.github.io/posts/transformer/#multi-head-attention-layer).

Comment: Thank you, I understand.